# Kernels that run fast on Multicores but relatively slow on GPU

Tags: cuda, multicore, gpu, gpgpu

Can someone suggest list of algorithms in which Multicores give superior performance compared to GPUs? I know that hybrid approach will still be faster, but what I am really looking for is to understand areas in which GPU still lag behind multicores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order of suitability from least suitable to most suitable:

- GPUs can only accelerate SIMD type workloads, so they are no good for task-parallel operations (like make -jN).
- GPUs don't have much cache and their atomic ops are relatively slow compared to CPUs; so they are nowhere near as good as CPUs with pointer-based structures such as trees.
- Workloads such as image processing or computer vision are in a gray area where the GPU advantages (texture mapping hardware, more cores) may be offset by the CPU advantages (better SIMD integer support, much higher clock rate).  If the actual processing is done in floating point, it's probably a wash or slight advantage to the GPU; if the processing is done in integer and can be mapped onto SSE2 instructions, the CPU will crush the GPU.

GPUs excel at data-parallel workloads that use a lot of single-precision floating-point.

Any workload getting offloaded to the GPU also incurs data transfer costs.

Comment: Yes, I know pointer chasing algorithms have problem of spatial locality and that GPUs have smaller caches. But GPU's can hide long memory latencies through hardware multi-threading. In terms of floating point performance GPU's are superior and integer based computations are superior on Multi-cores. Can we then say that pointer chasing algorithms based on integer computations have higher chances of running slow on GPUs than Multicores ?

Comment: I wouldn't even group them - I would say that GPUs are worse at computations that rely on narrow integer support (e.g. median computations, which are just scads of element-wise min/max calculations on corresponding integers), and also are worse at pointer-chasing.

They also are well-nigh incapable of general-purpose, task-parallel computing (like parallel make).  The segregated cores of the CPU are well-suited to tasks where the different cores are doing totally different things that happen to be parallelizable.

Answer (score 0):

Some guys at Intel did some research, where they compared scientific computations on modern multi-core CPUs and GPUs. Maybe you find that interesting. Figure 1 on page 5 shows the results.

Lee et al, "Debunking the 100X GPU vs. CPU Myth: An Evaluation of Throughput Computing on CPU and GPU":
http://www.hwsw.hu/kepek/hirek/2010/06/p451-lee.pdf